# Custom Scrollbar Maths in jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, touch-event

I am currently working on a project which uses a custom scroll plugin (written by me) to allow an element to be scrolled in touch devices, as well as desktop browsers. Everything is working correctly (including velocity and deceleration a la iOS).

However, the only problem that remains is calculating the top (or left) position of the scrollbar when a user scrolls. I have calculated the height of the scrollbar with the following formular:

```
Math.round((container.height() / content.height()) * 100);
```

This seems to compute the correct height of the bar, but now I need a formular to work out by how much the scrollbar's position should be moved when the user scrolls. I have checked through Google and wasn't able to find much of use, and also searched here on SO and would welcome any comments.

I have the following data available for use in the formula:

- Container height
- Content height
- Current scroll position (`scrollTop`)
- Height of scrollbar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

position of the scrollbar should be calculated by this formula:

```
Math.round((scrollbar.height * scrollTop / content.height());
```

Comment: In addition: scrollbar.height should be calculated by this formula:
`Math.round((scrollbarArea.height * container.height / content.height());`
Usually scrollbarArea.height = container.height

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid that this doesn't seem to work. For example, here is how the calculation looks after some scrolling has occurred:

358 * 33 / 698 = 17
358 * 40 / 698 = 21
358 * 54 / 698 = 28

Could you help? I think it's a problem with the calculation of the position, rather than the height of the scrollbar (I used your formula for the scrollbar.height, too).