# Draw Zoomable Time Line With Scroll Bars On Html5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, user-interface, html5-canvas, timeline

I need a Time Line For My Web Project.
Something like [this](http://vorg.github.com/timeline.js/examples/cssAnimation.html) - I read the code of this Time Line but did not understand it because it is not documented enough.

My problem is the math behind all of this (not the interaction with the canvas).
I [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374273/scrollbar-math-formula-bug) [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257421/custom-scrollbar-maths-in-jquery-javascript?rq=1) [several](http://csdgn.org/inform/scrollbar-mechanics) articles about the math of the scroll bars, but none of them talk about zoom.
Some 
[articles](http://digitalarts.bgsu.edu/faculty/bonniem/Spring11/artc4330_1/notes/notes35.html) suggest to hold canvas element with very large width value - and to display just the 
[View Port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewport).
I don't think that's the right way to do it -  I want to draw just the correct viewport.

In my project, I have array of `n` points.
Each point holds time value represented in seconds, but not all of the points are within the Viewp Port.

Considering the current zoom level, how do I calculate:

What points should be drawn and where to draw them?

What is the size and position of the thumb?

Any articles / tutorials about such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use something like [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) which handles the placement of points, as well as zooming and panning. [Here's](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/navigate.html) an example of that.

There are a bunch of other drawing libraries, [here a good list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890434/javascript-library-for-drawing-graphs-over-timelines-zoomable-and-selectable).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
The links are pretty cool.
But I prefer to build my own Time Line because I like to study the concept/math of the scrollbars…
Any article/book/code snippet on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

You always have Raphealjs.com , one of the most used library to play with SVG, with this you can write your own js to generate the timeline.