# Scrollbar height formula not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a custom scrollbar. I got stuck calculating the correct height for the scrollbar thumb. I did what [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257421/custom-scrollbar-maths-in-jquery-javascript#comment13190186_10259404) said to do (and other places I checked said the same formula):

```
scrollbarArea.offsetHeight * container.offsetHeight / content.scrollHeight
```

I did the same thing, but the scrollbars thumb is smaller than expected. How can I get the scrollbars thumb to be a regular height based on the height, and scrollHeight?

#### JSFiddle

```js
console.clear();

var innerWrapper = document.getElementById('innerWrapper');
var scrollBarThumb = document.getElementById('scrollbar_thumb');

scrollBarThumb.style.height = (2 * innerWrapper.scrollHeight / innerWrapper.scrollHeight) + 'px';
console.log(innerWrapper.scrollHeight, innerWrapper.offsetHeight);
```

```css
#outerWrapper {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: burlywood;
}
#content {
  width: 400px;
}
#scrollbar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#scrollbar_thumb {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <div id="innerWrapper">
    <div id="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae
      libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse
      vitae libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia
      Suspendisse vitae libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla.
      Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan
      nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque
      accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem
      lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="scrollbar">
    <div id="scrollbar_thumb"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explicitly state what you expected to happen and what did happen that was wrong.

Comment: What is `scrollBarThumb.style.height = (2 * innerWrapper.scrollHeight / innerWrapper.scrollHeight) + 'px';` intended to be? It will always be 2px.  2* X/X=2*1=2.

Comment: @Makyen The scrollbars thumb is too small. If you run the code, you'll see it's only 2px.

Comment: @Makyen I meant `scrollBarThumb.style.height = (2 * scrollBarThumb.parentElement.offsetHeight / innerWrapper.scrollHeight) + 'px';`, but the results are the same. What is the correct formula?

Comment: There is no `2` in the formula you have given: `scrollbarArea.offsetHeight * container.offsetHeight / content.scrollHeight`  Your formula should be either : `scrollBarThumb.style.height = (scrollBarThumb.parentElement.offsetHeight * innerWrapper.offsetHeight / innerWrapper.scrollHeight) + 'px';` or  `scrollBarThumb.style.height = (innerWrapper.offsetHeight * innerWrapper.offsetHeight / innerWrapper.scrollHeight) + 'px';`

Comment: @Makyen That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the formula you have stated you desire:

```
scrollbarArea.offsetHeight * container.offsetHeight / content.scrollHeight
```

You could use either

```
scrollBarThumb.style.height = (Math.pow(innerWrapper.offsetHeight,2)/ innerWrapper.scrollHeight) + 'px';
```

or

```
var scrollBarArea = document.getElementById('scrollbar');
scrollBarThumb.style.height = (scrollBarArea.offsetHeight * innerWrapper.offsetHeight / innerWrapper.scrollHeight) + 'px';
```

Full code:

```js
console.clear();


var innerWrapper = document.getElementById('innerWrapper');
var scrollBarArea = document.getElementById('scrollbar');
var scrollBarThumb = document.getElementById('scrollbar_thumb');

//Target formula:
//scrollbarArea.offsetHeight * container.offsetHeight / content.scrollHeight
//Either
scrollBarThumb.style.height = (scrollBarArea.offsetHeight * innerWrapper.offsetHeight / innerWrapper.scrollHeight) + 'px';
//or
//scrollBarThumb.style.height = (Math.pow(innerWrapper.offsetHeight,2)/ innerWrapper.scrollHeight) + 'px';
console.log(innerWrapper.scrollHeight, innerWrapper.offsetHeight);
```

```css
#outerWrapper {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: burlywood;
}
#content {
  width: 400px;
}
#scrollbar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#scrollbar_thumb {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <div id="innerWrapper">
    <div id="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae
      libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse
      vitae libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia
      Suspendisse vitae libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla.
      Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan
      nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque
      accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem
      lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="scrollbar">
    <div id="scrollbar_thumb"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```